# Assistance with understanding open covers

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question which I'm trying to understand,

Consider the interval of $[b,c]$ where $M$ is a collection of open sets and $[b,c] \subset \bigcup_{N \in M} N $ with

$$A=\left\{x \in [b,c]:\text{there is a finite }F \subset M\\\text{ such that }[b,x] \subseteq \bigcup_{N \in F} N\right \}\,.$$

We also assume that $b<c$ and $\alpha=\operatorname{lub}(A)$. Prove that $b< \alpha \leq c$.

Would using the Lindelöf Property be a good direction to go and solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to show that $A$ has at least one member that is bigger than $b$ and that every member of $A$ is $\le c$. The latter is trivial from the definition of $A$; for the former think about the fact that $b\in N$ for some $N\in M$.

Comment: Given that $A$ is by definition a subset of $[b,c]$, what could its least upper bound possibly be?

Comment: Well the least upper bound would be the supremum in this case, which is by definition.